# Aligning controls inside cells of a TableLayout

Tags: c#, winforms

In the picture below I have defined a 6-row table layout and placed controls inside its cells, in one cell goes the Label, the other cell for the control its self (a text box for example )

The problem is caused by that field options radio box, it will make the cell so big so then the text box that is under "Preview Data Value" label, goes way below...

How do you suggest fixing this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my prior experience, I would not use the table layout at all.  Instead I would set the anchors on each control to dynamically change with resize.

But if you insist on using the table layout, perhaps you should change the RowSpan attribute of the Preview Data Value cell, and have the label at the top with the text box underneath.

Another option would be to use a container like a GroupBox with a title Attribute that you can set to "Preview Data Value", put the text box in that container and set the "Dock" Attribute to "Fill".  Then from the looks of it, you don't even need the last Row.

See [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx) if you want to go totally nuts and implement your own drawing.

Comment: you mean set row span of "Preview Data Value" to "2" ? and place its text box on seventh row?

Comment: Ok I understood, you mean a whole row just for the label... cool, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make a seventh row and have the option group span two rows.

Comment: you mean set row span of "Preview Data Value" to "2" ? and place its text box on seventh row?

Comment: Ok I understod, you mean a whole row just for the label... cool, thanks.